# Replace the empty cells of one raster with the values of a second raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, arcgis-10.6, con

I have 2 rasters with the same extent. In the first raster, there are a lot of empty cells that I want to replace by the values of the second raster.
I have tried Raster calculation with the following expression...

```
Con(IsNull("DTM_Clip_Clip1"),"DSM_Clip","DTM_Clip_Clip1")
```

I don't get an error message, but no output is created?

I also tried Mosaic to new raster, but also here there is no output and no error message?

I use ArcGIS 10.6 Desktop.

Comment: Pay close attention to the documentation for `Con`. The output is a Raster, which needs to be saved to be manifested permanently on disk. Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact version of software

Answer (score 2):

Quoting example three from the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm), proper use of `Con` includes a final step:

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = "C:/sapyexamples/data"
inRaster1 = Raster("landuse")
inRaster2 = Raster("landuse2")
outCon = Con(((inRaster1 == 1) & (inRaster2 == 5)), inRaster1 + inRaster2, 99)
outCon.save("C:/sapyexamples/output/outcon")
```

In fact, these are the final steps of each of the five examples:

```py
outCon2.save("C:/sapyexamples/output/outcon2")
outCon.save("C:/sapyexamples/output/outcon")
outCon.save("C:/sapyexamples/output/outcon")
outCon.save("C:/sapyexamples/output/outcon")
outCon2.save("C:/sapyexamples/output/outcon2")
```

So it is not exactly correct to state that "no output is created", when what was created was what is documented as being created, a `Raster`. Unfortunately, since you didn't assign the object to a Python variable, the object was immediately freed (pending the garbage collector's pleasure), and all access to the result was lost.

If you want to preserve your result, you'll need to capture the output and use the `save` method as well:

```py
result = Con(IsNull("DTM_Clip_Clip1"),"DSM_Clip","DTM_Clip_Clip1")
result.save('my_revised_dtm.tif')
```